# Calling a var outside of a function

Tags: javascript

How can I call `customerId` outside of the function?

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      console.log("User ID:",userId);

      var database = firebase.database();
      var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      database.ref('stripe_customers/' + userId + '/customer_id').once('value', snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
             var customerId = snapshot.val();
             console.log(customerId);
          }
      });
```

Comment: Simply `return` `customerId`, and then you'll have the value when you call the function.

Comment: Can you maybe show me how? Very confusing to me. Kinda jumped it head first....

Comment: @ObsidianAge It's inside a callback though. Is just updating an outer variable an option? (`customerId` is a plain variable, not a function you can call)

Comment: Seems to be where I am falling short... @certainperformance